# Retrieve properties value dynamically on run-time for a Mule flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, properties-file, anypoint-studio

I have a requirement like an id will be passed through HTTP request and depending on that ID i need to invoke dynamically the properties values.

For one ID I need properties like

`dgc.metamodel.CommunityToSync=Community1
dgc.metamodel.DomainToSync=Domain1`

For another ID I need like

`dgc.metamodel.CommunityToSync=Community2
dgc.metamodel.DomainToSync=Domain2`

Is it possible to do this in Mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, property file will be read at the first time server is run. Although there are many properties only one key (unique) which will be referenced.

However to accommodate this requirement, I think we should utilizing Java code. This code will responsible to read the certain property file based on request (id). Then read the property and set it to variable for further usage:

```
private Properties prop = new Properties();
private InputStream input = null;

public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {    
    String id = ((ParameterMap)message.getInboundProperty("http.query.params")).get("id");
    input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../property" + id + ".properties");
    prop.load(input);

    message.setInvocationProperty("communityToSync", prop.getProperty("dgc.metamodel.CommunityToSync"));
    message.setInvocationProperty("domainToSync", prop.getProperty("dgc.metamodel.DomainToSync"));
```

I tested it with a simple flow

```
<flow name="propertyFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/prop" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-transformer class="example.ReadProperty" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger message="CommunityToSync = #[flowVars.communityToSync], DomainToSync = #[flowVars.domainToSync]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Execute it through browser: http://localhost:8081/prop?id=1 or http://localhost:8081/prop?id=2 to get the different result.

Comment: I am getting an exception while starting the Mule server and deployment failed with error as `Error creating bean with name 'propertyFlow': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'messageProcessors'; Cannot convert value of type [test_project.ReadProperty] to required type [org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor] for property 'messageProcessors[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found` I am passing message as return value for this transformMessage method.

Comment: I fixed the issue by extending class AbstractMessageTransformer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by reading the properties into a Map first:

You can load them directly into a map using Spring like so:

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="appProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="singleton" value="true"/>
            <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
```

And access it dynamically in your flow using MEL similar to:

```
 <logger message="My prop #[app.registry.appProps[flowVars.someKey]]" level="INFO" />
```

And you can build the key string however you want.

Comment: The issue is how to read the property (with the same key) from different file, dynamically during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with groovy to check bsed up on your requirement and send the properties as required.